# Detect push notifications tap

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, apple-push-notifications

I know you can use this code for handling your notifications :

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{
    if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive || application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground  )
   {//opened from a push notification when the app was on background
    }
}
```

But this isn't reliable it does loops with number of current notifications so it shows my view controller hundres of time

So my question is :

is there any other "good" way we can use it to handle only the tapped notification ?

Comment: Actually, this is the good way... what are you doing in this function? did you put a breakpoint or NSLog in it to test the notification that you are receiving? is it the same all the time?!

Comment: I have no issues when I'm receiving only one notification . But if I got a lot of notifications then the function send them all to my view controller but only the taped one take the UserInfo var so yes I'm getting the tapped one but many times

Comment: That's not how this method works. You're doing something else wrong.

Comment: Lance I'm using NSNotificationCenter maybe that's what causing the problem